# Modal View's toolbar is obscured. MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, modalviewcontroller, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am trying to bring up an Email Window in my application, however the top toolbar that is suppose to have Cancel and Send is being obscured by the navigation controller.

I believe the reason is that I am calling

```
 if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
            MFMailComposeViewController* controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
            controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
            [controller setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"internalapps@microstrategy.com"]];
            [controller setSubject:@"Mobile HelpDesk App"];
            [controller setMessageBody:@"" isHTML:NO];
            if (controller){
                [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:^{}];
            }

        }
```

From a child ViewController that controls a view inside a scrollview (For Paging).

How do I get the toolbar to be on top of the navigation bar? Right now, it's only showing the new email window, but I cannot cancel or send the email.

I tried using `[self.parentViewController presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:^{}];`, but that didn't do anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `presentViewController:...` from a view controller whose view isn't at the top of the view hierarchy (and so most likely doesn't occupy the whole screen). As you've seen, this results in a presented view which is perhaps partially visible and perhaps doesn't respond to touches in some areas.

Trying `self.parentViewController` is the correct solution (though the code you show is invalid). You need to ensure that you navigate far enough up the hierarchy to get to the 'root' view controller and present from there.

Comment: Okay.. wow I didn't realize it had to be presented at the Root of the Nav Controller. Is there anyway to call all the way back to the root from this view controller? It's probably at least 3-4 VCs up.

Comment: The UIViewController convenience methods probably won't be able to deal with your hierarchy if it's that complex so you'll need to put something in to handle the navigation yourself.

Comment: So I created a NSNotification so that it would notify the root controller that I want to show the Email form. It works now! Hopefully it's the most efficient solution. Thanks for the help Wain!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it could be as simple as changing:

```
 [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

to

```
 [self.navigationController presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: yea... that didn't work. It may be because the view controller is buried 3 levels down from the root.